# Nodejs https.request head method issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

Have a problem with nodejs, https.request returns <http.ClientRequest>

```
const checkStatus = await https
  .request(
    {
      method: 'HEAD',
      host: 'host',
      path: 'path',
    },
    (response) => {
      const { statusCode } = response;
      // idk
    },
  )
  .on('error', (e) => {
    if (e) {
      throw new Error();
    }
  })
  .end();
```

Can i somehow return statusCode instead <http.ClientRequest> inside checkStatus variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can only usefully `await` a promise but `https.request` does not return a promise.

Either:

- [Wrap it in a `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) *or*
- Replace it with a library which supports promises by default (such as Axios or node-fetch)

```js
(async function () {

    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
    const response = await axios.head(url);
    console.log(response.status);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.21.1/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you, i think i should wrap it to new Promise, axios is too slow

Comment: I'd be surprised if, in a system making HTTP requests, any CPU bounds would be significant.